# Extreme Bad thoughts about prophet muhammad saw

Tags: evil-thoughts

Asalamualikum
I always suffer from extreme bad thoughts particularly about prophet muhammad pbuh and i have read a lot of online data and watched videos of scholars that it is the waswas of shaytaan but i am not able to stop myself from paying attention to these thoughts.i also tend to feel sometime that these are my own thoughts.i am not able to ignore these thoughts.and at height seldom i tend to repeat these thoughts in my mind and head and often feel an extreme tempation to say these in my heart.kindly help and pray for me

Comment: Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor.

Comment: I have to add that I really hate un-commented downvotes. Even a bad question does not deserve dovnvote without explanation.

Comment: To help you would include knowing the nature and details of your bad thoughts, but telling that here would very sure be considered offensive and attract hate and even more downvotes. Seek a trustworthy Counselor, one that tries to understand the reasons, not one of those that shoot on sight.

Comment: And again, reading your question, might it be that you think bad just about everything, your neighbors, your spouse, your house, your car or donkey? And thinking bad about the Prophet is just the top that makes you aware that somethings not right? If so, this would not be not so much a religious problem but rather a medical condition.

Comment: And yet again, there really are bad neighbors, bad spouses and bad donkeys. Did you ever drive a Chevrolet? You have to get out of the mood of "I hate everything".

Answer (score 0):

‏سلام عليكم

you should try to stay away from things on the media that evolves Islam because the media isn’t ran by anyone but kufr. if you want to gain knowledge about the religion read read read. having thought like this can put you in the state of kufr when you die you won’t be a Muslim. it’s scary. read about the deen and stop looking at social media. pray always, and go the the masjid. surround yourself around good Muslim people.

May Allah swt guide us all

‏الله اعلم